# setSelection() in a few spinner work incorrect

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I have three `spinner` with same custom `SimpleCurosAdapter`

```
    spinnerX = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerX);
    spinnerY = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerY);
    spinnerZ = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerZ);
    spinnerX.setAdapter(new SpinnerAd(this, R.layout.my_item, c, from, to));
    spinnerY.setAdapter(new SpinnerAd(this, R.layout.my_item, c, from, to));
    spinnerZ.setAdapter(new SpinnerAd(this, R.layout.my_item, c, from, to));
```

And when i call (for example):

```
    spinnerX.setSelection(1);
    spinnerY.setSelection(7);
    spinnerZ.setSelection(3);
```

ALL three spinners `setSelection` like last one... at position `3`.
Why?

**All spinners has same data (one cursor)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, but i do not understand why does it matter, becouse

`c == dbRead.query(CalcDBHelper.TABLE_VARIABLES, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

Solution, set adapter like this:

```
        spinnerX.setAdapter(new SpinnerAd(this, R.layout.formula_variable_item, ActMain.dbRead.query(CalcDBHelper.TABLE_VARIABLES, null, null, null, null, null, null), from, to));
        spinnerY.setAdapter(new SpinnerAd(this, R.layout.formula_variable_item, ActMain.dbRead.query(CalcDBHelper.TABLE_VARIABLES, null, null, null, null, null, null), from, to));
        spinnerZ.setAdapter(new SpinnerAd(this, R.layout.formula_variable_item, ActMain.dbRead.query(CalcDBHelper.TABLE_VARIABLES, null, null, null, null, null, null), from, to));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all three objects point to the same instance ? (the same resource as loaded from the XML)

Comment: So it looks like each adapter needs its own (unshared) cursor. Interesting, but makes sense I guess. (Conjecture: The spinners move in sync because the underlying code uses the cursor's move-to function to 'pick' the selected value, and if all three spinners use the same cursor, then they'll move in sync ?)

Comment: agreed with the suggestion